# Additional variable in struct causes wrong return value in getter method

Tags: c, struct, return-value, getter

I'm very new to programming in C, but I have been using Java for years. I created a struct with two variables and a getter method (DFA_get_size) to return the value of one. However, when I added a third variable (the one commented out) the function DFA_get_size began to return the wrong number. I don't understand why this is happening. Please help.

Below is the entire program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct DFA {
    int nstates;
    //int trans;
    int ai;
} DFA;

extern DFA DFA_new(int nstates){
    DFA dfa;
    dfa.nstates = nstates; 
    dfa.ai = 0;
}

extern int DFA_get_size(DFA dfa){
    return dfa.nstates; 
}

int main(){
    DFA test = DFA_new(8);
    printf("%d\n", DFA_get_size(test));
}
```

Comment: Please check about scope of variable dfa in function DFA_new, it is local to the function

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually returning anything from `DFA_new`. Add a `return dfa;`, and crank up the warnings when you compile (`-Wall` for most compilers).

Comment: But the DFA created in DFA_new will go out of scope when DFA_new returns.

Comment: It returns a DFA, but since you didn't `return dfa;` from the function the DFA it returns isn't the one you initialized in the function, it's just whatever garbage was in the memory at the location of the return value. The code likely worked because that *happened* to be your dfa.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like an idiot. I literally just started learning C yesterday so I have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Don't, it's an easy mistake to make. I still do it sometimes… just **always** compile with `-Wall` (and maybe `-Wextra`); the compiler can catch a lot of stuff for you if you let it.

Answer (score 0):

The DFA object that you create in DFA_new goes out of scope.  You need to either malloc a pointer to a DFA object in new and return that. Or pass a pointer to a DFA object into DFA_new to initialize it.  I think you were just getting lucky first time with only two members of the struct.

Comment: Or return the value of the DFA structure.  You can return copies of local structures; you can’t afford to return pointers to local structures.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not returning a value in DFA_new.  But, actually, you also don't want to be passing structures around as arguments or as return values anyway.  Usually in C you would pass a pointer to structures so you do not have to copy the whole thing around all the time.

This code solves the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct DFA {
    int nstates;
    int trans;
    int ai;
} DFA;

void DFA_new(int nstates, DFA * dfa){
    dfa->nstates = nstates; 
    dfa->ai = 0;
    dfa->trans = 0;  // might as well initialize this one too
}

extern int DFA_get_size(DFA * dfa){
    return dfa->nstates; 
}

int main(){
    DFA test;
    DFA_new(8, &test);
    printf("%d\n", DFA_get_size(&test));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dfa instance in this function is local to the function, so once you leave the function it ceases to exist since you do not return it from the function.

```
DFA DFA_new(int nstates){
    DFA dfa;
    dfa.nstates = nstates; 
    dfa.ai = 0;
    /* missing return dfa; */
}
```

Returning a struct is not very effective since it copies the contents of the struct. There are other ways you can do this:

Declaring the variable before passing it to DFA_new

```
DFA dfa;
int myNstates = 0;
int myAi = 0;
DFA_New(&dfa, myNstates, myAi ); // DFA_New(DFA*,int,int);
```

or allocating the DFA on the heap and passing a pointer to that element (don't forget to free it when you are done with it)

```
DFA* DFA_new(int nstates){
    DFA* dfa = malloc(sizeof(*dfa));
    if (dfa == NULL)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "No memory\n" );
       abort();
    }
    dfa->nstates = nstates; 
    dfa->ai = 0;
    return dfa;
}

/* then later doing free() on the returned pointer */
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning DFA while creating it :

```
extern DFA DFA_new(int nstates){
    DFA dfa;
    dfa.nstates = nstates; 
    dfa.ai = 0;
    return DFA;
}
```

In C,local variable will be destroyed once you return from the function. since you are not returning anything, you wont get proper structure in main statement.